# How can I create a champion in league of legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

My wish is to create a League of Legends champion that I want. I'd like to know how to create a champion and send it to Riot. I'd also like a link to the policy of the creator system, if one exists. Thank you for your knowledge.

Comment: I think Riot does not have a formal process for this and probably avoids using their customers ideas, likely due to legal complications this would cause. In order to REALLY create an entire champion for them, your best bet is to submit an application to work for them.

Comment: Not that I agree with the question, but wouldn't this be better on the Game Dev SE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you referred 10.000 friends to League of Legends until April 25th 2012 you were able to fly to Riot Games HQ and design a champion with them.

Source: [RaF Design a Champ](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Refer_A_Friend)

However this was removed and now there is no official way to suggest Riot Games Champions you "invented", except for the forum.

In the forums you can post under the [Champion/Item Feedback](http://forums.euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/forumdisplay.php?f=48) section your ideas and hope that it will get lots of upvotes, so a Riot employee looks at it, but it is very unlikely that a community-created champion sees the light of Summoner's Rift.